# ORA-00904 when trying to use Oracle TABLE() function in a UDT column passed as a function parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Given the following type hierarchy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VC_MNumber AS Object (   
  idno NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION   typeDimension   RETURN NUMBER ,
  MEMBER FUNCTION typeName RETURN VARCHAR2) NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VC_MReal UNDER VC_MNumber(   
  YDCCoeff NUMBER,
  CbDCCoeff NUMBER,
  CrDCCoeff NUMBER,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION  typeDimension   RETURN NUMBER, 
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION typeName RETURN VARCHAR2) FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY VC_MReal AS
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION typeDimension RETURN NUMBER IS
    var_dimension       number :=  10;
    BEGIN
        RETURN var_dimension;
    END;
   OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION typeName RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    var_typeName        VARCHAR2(400) :=  'VC_MREAL';
    BEGIN
        RETURN var_typeName;
    END;
END;
/
```

And the table:

CREATE TABLE cophirfv_int (
id NUMBER,
fv VC_MReal
);

I am trying to execute the function:

```
create or replace function sum_MNumber
(
    inn_FV VC_MNumber,
    out_FV VC_MNumber
) return NUMBER is
   sql_stmt1 varchar2(400);
   total_sum number := 0;
   inn_val number;
   cur_type varchar2(400);
   var_cur_type_name varchar2(400);
BEGIN
    FOR cur_type IN (select attr_name from user_type_attrs where type_name='VC_MREAL')
        LOOP    


        var_cur_type_name := cur_type.attr_name;

        dbms_output.put_line(var_cur_type_name);

        sql_stmt1 := 'SELECT ifv.' || var_cur_type_name ||' FROM TABLE(inn_FV.'|| var_cur_type_name ||') ifv';

        dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt1);

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt1 INTO inn_val;

        --total_sum := total_sum + inn_val;
    END LOOP;
    return 2;
END;
/
```

Through the query:

```
select sum_MNumber(fv,fv) from cophirfv_int;
```

But I am getting the error ORA-00904: "INN_FV"."CRDCCOEFF" Invalid identifier on the line:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt1 INTO inn_val;
```

Someone know what is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: What you are doing appears overly complicated that I think you are so far down the wrong rabbit hole that you need to take a step back and state what the problem is you are trying to solve (in English - not in code) because I think you don't need dynamic SQL but you have made things so convoluted I am unsure what you expect as your output.

Comment: Is there any philosophical justification for using objects here?

Comment: Ok... I need a function that gets all the attributes of a type that is within a type hierarchy.
I need to get the attributes values of the type and execute a math fomula on them (wich is generic, once the user can create a type in this hierarchy).
Is it possible?
It would be possible if I could associate the attributes with number for example... is it possible? ... so I could get them in a loop (get(0)...get(last_attribute)).

Comment: It is probably possible with the user_type_attrs.ATTR_NO. I am going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need dynamic SQL instead you can use the `IS OF( type )` operator and the `TREAT` function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d7d1/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create function sum_MNumber
(
    inn_FV VC_MNumber,
    out_FV VC_MNumber
) return NUMBER
IS
  total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  IF inn_FV IS OF( VC_MReal ) THEN
    total := total + TREAT( inn_FV AS VC_Mreal ).YDCCoeff
                   + TREAT( inn_FV AS VC_Mreal ).CbDCCoeff
                   + TREAT( inn_FV AS VC_Mreal ).CrDCCoeff;
  END IF;
  IF out_FV IS OF( VC_MReal ) THEN
    total := total + TREAT( out_FV AS VC_Mreal ).YDCCoeff
                   + TREAT( out_FV AS VC_Mreal ).CbDCCoeff
                   + TREAT( out_FV AS VC_Mreal ).CrDCCoeff;
  END IF;
  RETURN total;
END;
/

INSERT INTO cophirfv_int VALUES ( 1, VC_MReal( 1, 3, 4, 5 ) )
/

INSERT INTO cophirfv_int VALUES ( 2, VC_MReal( 2, 1, 3, 4 ) )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
select sum_MNumber(fv,fv) from cophirfv_int
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d7d1/1/0)**:

```
| SUM_MNUMBER(FV,FV) |
|--------------------|
|                 24 |
|                 16 |
```

## Alternative

Or you could define an approriate member function in the types:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/296c1/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VC_MNumber AS Object (   
  idno NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION total RETURN NUMBER
) NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VC_MReal UNDER VC_MNumber(   
  YDCCoeff NUMBER,
  CbDCCoeff NUMBER,
  CrDCCoeff NUMBER,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION total RETURN NUMBER
) FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY VC_MReal AS
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION total RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN self.YDCCoeff + self.CbDCCoeff + self.CrDCCoeff;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE cophirfv_int ( id NUMBER, fv VC_MReal )
/

INSERT INTO cophirfv_int VALUES ( 1, VC_MReal( 1, 3, 4, 5 ) )
/

INSERT INTO cophirfv_int VALUES ( 2, VC_MReal( 2, 1, 3, 4 ) )
/

create or replace function sum_MNumber
(
    inn_FV VC_MNumber,
    out_FV VC_MNumber
) return NUMBER
IS
  total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  RETURN inn_Fv.total() + out_FV.total();
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
select sum_MNumber(fv,fv) from cophirfv_int
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/296c1/1/0)**:

```
| SUM_MNUMBER(FV,FV) |
|--------------------|
|                 24 |
|                 16 |
```

Comment: I need a generic solution. 
These solution could solve the problem of this type specifically... but it is not generic.

Comment: @Siqueira Why do you need a generic solution? You have to compile the types and if you redeclare them then you will invalidate the function and know that you need to recompile it with the correct type attributes. Also, if you declare the function on the type instance (as per my second example) then you can just call it for each type and you don't need to make it messy with anything dynamic.

Comment: I need it generic because I am going to deal with many math functions... if I do it like the way you posted, the system is going to be quite hard to maintain and work with.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic SQL:

***(I do not believe using this is a good idea and am only posting it as a proof-of-concept. Instead you should be defining `OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION`s on each sub-type, as in my other answer, and calling those)***

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71408/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum_MNumber
(
  i_FV VC_MNumber
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  value NUMBER;
  total NUMBER := 0;
  type_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  attr_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT t.type_name,
         attr_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO
         type_names,
         attr_names
  FROM   USER_TYPE_ATTRS a
         INNER JOIN
         USER_TYPES t
         ON ( a.type_name = t.type_name )
  WHERE  t.TYPEID = SYS_TYPEID( i_FV );

  FOR i IN 1 .. type_names.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'BEGIN :1 := TREAT(:2 AS "' || type_names(i) || '")."' || attr_names(i) || '"; END;'
      USING OUT value, i_FV;
    total := total + value;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN total;
END;
/

INSERT INTO cophirfv_int VALUES ( 1, VC_MReal( 1, 3, 4, 5 ) )
/

INSERT INTO cophirfv_int VALUES ( 2, VC_MReal( 2, 1, 3, 4 ) )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
select sum_MNumber(fv) from cophirfv_int
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71408/2/0)**:

```
| SUM_MNUMBER(FV) |
|-----------------|
|              13 |
|              10 |
```